# Problems with sending a multipart/alternative email with PHP

Tags: php, email

Here's the script that's builds/sends the email:

```
$boundary = md5(date('U'));

$to = $email;
$subject = "My Subject";

$headers = "From: myaddress@mydomain.com" . "\r\n".
           "X-Mailer: PHP/".phpversion() ."\r\n".
           "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n".
           "Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=--$boundary". "\r\n".
           "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit". "\r\n";

$text = "You really ought remember the birthdays";     
$html = '<html>
    <head>
      <title>Birthday Reminders for August</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <p>Here are the birthdays upcoming in August!</p>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th>Person</th><th>Day</th><th>Month</th><th>Year</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Joe</td><td>3rd</td><td>August</td><td>1970</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Sally</td><td>17th</td><td>August</td><td>1973</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </body>
    </html>
    ';

$message = "Multipart Message coming up" . "\r\n\r\n".
       "--".$boundary.
       "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"" .
       "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit".
       $text. 
       "--".$boundary. 
       "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"". 
       "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit". 
       $html.
       "--".$boundary."--";



mail("toAddress@example.com", $subject, $message, $headers);
```

It sends the message just fine, and my recipient receives it, but they get the whole thing in text/plain instead of in multipart/alternative.  Viewing the source of the received message gives this (lots of cruft removed):

```
Delivered-To: myrecipient@example.com
Received: by 10.90.100.4 with SMTP id x4cs111413agb;
    Wed, 25 Mar 2009 16:39:32 -0700 (PDT)
Received: by 10.100.153.6 with SMTP id a6mr85081ane.123.1238024372342;
    Wed, 25 Mar 2009 16:39:32 -0700 (PDT)
Return-Path: <xxx@xxxx.com>
--- snip ---
Date: Wed, 25 Mar 2009 17:37:36 -0600 (MDT)
Message-Id: <200903252337.n2PNbaw2019541@www.xxxxxxx.com>
To: trevor@saturdayplace.com
Subject: My Subject
From: me@mydomain.com
X-Mailer: PHP/4.3.9
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain;
boundary="--66131caf569f63b24f43d529d8973560"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
X-OriginalArrivalTime: 25 Mar 2009 23:38:30.0531 (UTC) FILETIME=[CDC4E530:01C9ADA2]
X-TM-AS-Product-Ver: SMEX-8.0.0.1181-5.600.1016-16540.005
X-TM-AS-Result: No--4.921300-8.000000-31
X-TM-AS-User-Approved-Sender: No
X-TM-AS-User-Blocked-Sender: No


Multipart Message coming up

--66131caf569f63b24f43d529d8973560
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="iso-8859-1"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

You really ought remember the birthdays

--66131caf569f63b24f43d529d8973560
Content-Type: text/html; charset="iso-8859-1"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<html>
    <head>
      <title>Birthday Reminders for August</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <p>Here are the birthdays upcoming in August!</p>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th>Person</th><th>Day</th><th>Month</th><th>Year</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Joe</td><td>3rd</td><td>August</td><td>1970</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Sally</td><td>17th</td><td>August</td><td>1973</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </body>
    </html>


--66131caf569f63b24f43d529d8973560--
```

It looks like the content-type header is getting changed along the way from multipart/alternative to text/plain.  I'm no sysadmin, so if this is a sendmail issue I'm in way over my head.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The line

```
"Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=--$boundary". "\r\n".
```

should be

```
"Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=$boundary". "\r\n".
```

You don't include the dashes in the header.

Comment: Gaaaaaa! - Thank RoBorg.  That was indeed it.

Comment: If anyone wondered why the initial script does not work - just add . "\r\n" to every line which $message consists of, not just at the first line ($message = "Multipart Message coming up" . "\r\n\r\n".) Ah, right, Sam Critchley had already pointed that out.

Answer (score 4):

To get this to work properly for me, I also needed to add a "\r\n" at the end of each header line, two of them ("\r\n\r\n") at the end of the lines before the text and html bodies, and one at the end of each body. This results in something like this:

```
$message = "Multipart Message coming up" . "\r\n\r\n".
       "--".$boundary."\r\n".
       "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\""."\r\n".
       "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit"."\r\n".
       $text."\r\n". 
       "--".$boundary."\r\n". 
       "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\""."\r\n". 
       "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit"."\r\n".
       $html."\r\n".
       "--".$boundary."--";
```

Comment: This is the only way it would work for me too. Its amazing how many examples there are online that leave this out.

Answer (score 2):

use "\n" instead of "\r\n" looks like it qmail has problems with "\r"

Comment: agree, i know by documenation its not correct but we often send mass mails to our customers, and magically if i use the \r on our server, messages go broken, but if i str_replace \r for empty'' (leaving the \n only) in both header and body makes the email arrive ok and display correctly in most clients /tested both desktop clients and webmails/

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought, but it might be a lot easier to simply worth with something like [phpmailer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer) or [Zend_Mail](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.mail.html).